# ERROR: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')" when compiling project with "Rollup", TypeScript, and StyledComponents

Tags: rollup

I'm trying to develop a component library in NPM using React, TypeScript and Styled-Components, but whenever I build the project and later try to render my button component on the screen I get the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')"

Detailing further the error I'm getting would be this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNjZZ.png)

When performing some tests I found that the problem is occurring because of the Styled-Components library, more specifically during the rendering of the component.

I looked at the file that the Rollup generates after the build and found the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajREP.png)

Regarding my project I have the following code:

**TS:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Mvw.png)

**Styled:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK5Dz.png)

**Rollup Config:**

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const pkg = require('./package.json');

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: pkg.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                sourceMap: true,
            },
            {
                file: pkg.module,
                format: 'esm',
                sourceMap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal(),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                plugins: ['babel-plugin-styled-components', {
                    namespace: 'appname-',
                    displayName: false,
                    fileName: false
                }]
            })
        ],
        external: ["react", "react-dom", "styled-components"],
        globals: { 'styled-components': 'styled', "react": "React" },
    },
    {
        input: 'dist/esm/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
];
```

**My Dependencies:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpFJ7.png)

What I've tried to do so far is configure Babel to add styled-components and followed some Rollup + Styled-Components configuration documentation, but in neither case was successful... Also, I haven't found any satisfactory answers on the internet regarding this problem.